# Heapify python method in a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

I'm tryng to figure out how I can use heapify function in a list of tuples.
i want it for djikstra algorithm so my list will look like this.

```
[(node,distance)(node2,distance2)....(node-n,distance-n]
```

I just wanna know how heapify can order my list just checking the distance and not the node in the tuple.

As I know, if i have a list'l' like:

```
[8,4,7,2]
```

and I use

```
heapify(l)
```

It will return:

```
[2,4,7,8]
```

So how I can use this function only ordering by distance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Heapify will work with lists of tuples such that the first element of each tuple is the value, so use (distance, node) instead